# ruby: print light, medium and dark shade character

Tags: ruby, windows, console

'Hi, i would like to print the old DOS characters 176 to 178 (filled cursor with gradients), unicode 2591, 2592 and 2593, light, medium and dark shade in ruby on a windows console, how to do it please ?

tried this

```
p "\u2592" #=> "\u2592"
p [176].pack('U*') => °
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `p`; use `print` (or `puts` if you want a trailing newline).  `p` displays things using `#inspect`, which gives you something you can copy and paste into source code, including quotation marks, etc. `print` and `puts` are the normal way to output text.

Assuming you have your encodings set up right in your program and console, then `print "\u2592"` and similar should work fine.  Although it can be tricky to set up a Windows console for Unicode, and you might want to look at some third-party console applications.